# Horizontal Content Layout with CSS

Tags: css

I have three elements that I am trying to layout horizontally. Currently, I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <h1>h1. Heading</h1>
  <h1 class="subheader">subheader</h1>
  <h1><small>segment header</small></h1>
</div>
```

When I run this, I see something like the following:

```
h1. Heading
subheader
segment header
```

However, I'd really like to get things laid out like the following:

```
h1. Heading subheader segment header
```

How do I setup this up via CSS in my root DIV?

Thank you

Comment: SEO-wise ==> it's not good to have more that one `h1` in your document

Comment: Please include the CSS you have tried.

Comment: Ugh! Why not `<h1>h1. Heading <span class="subheader">subheader</span><small>segment header</small></h1>`? It seems like you don't understand HTML and CSS, or at least their best practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aNiTEWa/1/edit)***

Add a class to your DIV

```
<div class="align_H1">
```

and do:

```
.align_H1 h1{
  display:inline;
}
```

So the trick is to `display:inline;` your `<h1>` elements, cause by default they are `display:block;` level elements.

Think about `inline` like on the *content* positioning flow,
while on `block` as for *layout*

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with inline vs block elements? It sounds like what you want is

```
 H1 {display:inline}
```

That said, it's usually not a great idea to break an element's default style when you might want its normal behaviour somewhere else. Instead, maybe give them a class, as per @Roko's answer.

CSS tricks has a handy reference on how to use the display property http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/